# Push object onto end of array using new literal syntax

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, objective-c-literals

PHP has:

```
arr[] = 'Push this onto my array';
```

Where the string will be added to the end of the array.

Is there any equivalent of this in the new Objective-C literal syntax? The most succinct way I can think of doing it is:

```
arr[arr.count] = @"Add me";
```

but maybe there's something better out there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [the documentation for the new literal syntax](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html). When you assign into an array using a subscript, the call is translated into the `setObject:atIndexedSubscript:` method call:

```
NSMutableArray *foo = …;
foo[0] = @"bar"; // => [foo setObject:@"bar" atIndexedSubscript:0];
```

If you had your own mutable array implementation, you could add a special case to the `setObject:atIndexedSubscript:` method to grow the array when assigning past the array size. <strike>I very much doubt the default `NSMutableArray` implementation does anything like it, most probably you’d just get an exception about index being out of bounds.</strike> And this is indeed what `NSMutableArray` does, see [the reference documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> If the index is equal to count the element is added to the end of the
>   array, growing the array.

Thank you Martin for the heads-up!

Comment: The `NSMutableArray` documentation for `setObject:atIndexedSubscript:` explicitely states: "If the index is equal to `count` the element is added to the end of the array, growing the array."

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually recommend doing this, but Objective-C *does* make it possible to extend the `setObject:atIndexedSubscript:` method with your own code. The process is called "method swizzling", and it's explained here: http://darkdust.net/writings/objective-c/method-swizzling

Here's some actual working code that demonstrates the process. The cool bit is in `main()`, where I'm able to use `fib[-1] = ...` instead of `fib[fib.count] = ...`. Of course there's no huge advantage here; the code is no more efficient, and certainly harder to read. But I do save having to write out "`fib`" twice.

A *major* disadvantage of this approach is that Objective-C doesn't really have any rules about the order in which categories get loaded, so if somebody else provided a category with similar functionality, it would be a toss-up which one got loaded last. (And if they happened to choose the same *name* for their category, it would be a toss-up which one got loaded at all, I think.)

So, bottom line, don't do this: but it is *possible.*

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface NSMutableArray (NegativeOne)
+(void)load;
-(void)swizzled_setObject:(id)obj atIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx;
@end

@implementation NSMutableArray (NegativeOne)

+(void)load
{
    Method original = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(setObject:atIndexedSubscript:));
    Method swizzled = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(swizzled_setObject:atIndexedSubscript:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzled);
}

-(void)swizzled_setObject:(id)obj atIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx
{
    if (idx == -1)  idx = [self count];
    [self swizzled_setObject:obj atIndexedSubscript:idx];  // go use the old method: not a typo!
}

@end

int main()
{
    int x = 0, y = 1;
    NSMutableArray *fib = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (int i=0; i < 10; ++i) {
        fib[-1] = @(x);  // wowie zowie!
        int temp = x+y;  x = y;  y = temp;
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", fib);
    return 0;
}
```